# Don't show anything on Graphical Layout Tab

Tags: android, eclipse

Everyway I tried:

1. Open With -> Android Layout Editor
2. Restart Eclipse
3. Upgrade Eclipse   and ADT to newest version

But Graphical Layout Tab not working :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either there is an issue with your theme, or the Device Configuration you selected does not have a layout that can be rendered correctly. Try selecting another Device Configuration and change the theme to see if that helps.

You can also check the Error Log (Window->Show View->Error Log) to see if there are any other issues.

Comment: As I said, the error is pointing to your Theme. Please change your Theme and then see if this works. Use a standard theme such as Theme.No_Title

Answer (score 0):

change your SS Galaxy Mini to something else or Restart your Eclipse

Comment: Yest ... i was change SS Galaxy mini and tried restart eclipse :(